# Extend Java Paramterized Interface from Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an interface 

`public interface Parser<Raw, Parsed> extends Func1<Raw, Parsed>`

Which I implement from a kotlin class:

`class ProgramParser : Parser<ProgramQuery.Data, Program>`

when I then try to write `Parser<ProgramQuery.Data, Program> parser = new ProgramParser();`

I get an error `Error:(60, 53) error: incompatible types: ProgramParser cannot be converted to Parser<Data,Program>`

Is there a different way for me to make an implementation of a java interface in Kotlin?

Comment: Are you missing `<>` in `new ProgramParser<>()`?

Comment: Might you happen to have any other `ProgramParser` in the namespace?

Comment: @hotkey only 1 ProgramParser Egor: I did not want it to be generic, the ProgramParser is the non generic implementation

Comment: It works for me, what Kotlin version are you on? Are you sure your imports are OK?

Comment: So you extend it in kotlin and use it later in java? (because `Parser<ProgramQuery.Data, Program> parser = new ProgramParser();` is not a valid kotlin code.